# Save automatically when focus is lost

Tags: textmate

How can I enable this feature? See 19.5 in this TextMate [Manual](http://manual.macromates.com/en/saving_files.html)

Comment: What have you tried yet? If you have tried any  settings and that won't worked for you then please tell us in your question too it will be helpful to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine you fill in the check box labelled "Safe files when focus is lost" and close the dialog box. Seems rather straightforward, given the documentation you provided.

However, if you have an older version of this software, that feature may not be available, at which point you will have to upgrade the software to get this feature.